# Как на языке JAVA запустить процесс с двумя аргументами в Ubuntu server

Tags: java, ubuntu

Есть один исполняемый файл, который вызывается с двумя аргументами, и после вызова возвращает текст в терминал. При вызове файла из терминала:

```
cd /home/gamedbd/gamedbd gamesys.conf listrole
```

В терминале выдаётся нормально текст. А вот с помощью java, как я не пытался, не хочет. Пробовал двумя способами:
1. `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/gamedbd/gamedbd gamesys.conf listrole");`
2.

```
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/home/gamedbd/gamedbd","gamesys.conf","listrole");

        // перенаправляем стандартный поток ошибок на
        // стандартный вывод
        procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        // запуск программы
        Process process = procBuilder.start();

        // читаем стандартный поток вывода
        // и выводим на экран
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isrStdout = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
        BufferedReader brStdout = new BufferedReader(isrStdout);

        String line = null;
        while((line = brStdout.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        // ждем пока завершится вызванная программа
        // и сохраняем код, с которым она завершилась в
        // в переменную exitVal
        int exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

ничего не хочет. И хотелось бы еще чтобы текст который выведет исполняемый файл можно было обрабатывать в самой java программе.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, в первый аргумент вставил полный путь к файлу конфигураций.

Answer (score -1):

У функции (или как это у вас называется? Методом?) два аргумента - `int argc` (счётчик аргументов. Его значение зависит от количества аргументов. Название екзекутабля - тоже аргумент) и `char* argv[]` (примерно так выглядит). Так вот `argv` - массив строк. Нулевым аргументом вроде как является название екзекутабля. А вот первый аргумент (`argv[1]`) - это уже первый аргумент из шелла.

*P. S. С джавой я работал немного. Писал больше на C, но java с C - языки одной группы, с похожим синтаксисом. Даже принципы работы с кодом похожи (хотя Java - полностью ООП). Так что если не поможет - не расстраивайтесь xD*